# Adding max and case to data?

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, max, partition-by

I'm trying to add a few things to my code here and alter this table, but I'm a bit of a greenhorn in SQL and I'm struggling to make the mental leap to find out how to connect a few things.

1. I'm trying to add a Partition by job to get row 1,2,3,4... (So job 21980 will have 3 rows)
2. I then want to add MAX of ROW NO by JOB (So essentially I want to display the highest of the rows for each job. So job 21980 has 3 rows, I want to just show value 3)
3. I then want to say: when the row number ISN'T the maximum row number, then I want the data in the rows to be ZERO for columns:  PO$$,  Wip Total, per pc, Standard Cost, DIFF,% of Profit

Current SQL to generate this data:

```
SELECT  [Job #],
        ,[Date]
        ,[Variance Amt]
        ,[Job QTY] 
        ,[OpenQty] 
        ,[Part #] 
        ,[Material] 
        ,[PCS #] 
        ,[Matrl$$] 
        ,[Date Last Issue] 
        ,case when substring([PurchaseOrders],len([PurchaseOrders]),1) = '|' then substring([PurchaseOrders],1,len([PurchaseOrders])-1) else [PurchaseOrders] end [PurchaseOrders] 
        ,[PO$$] 
        ,[Date Last Rcvd] 
        ,[Wip Total] 
        ,[per pc] 
        ,[Standard Cost] 
        ,[DIFF] 
        ,[% of Profit] 
        FROM [VarianceView] 
        Order By [Job #]
```

I kind of get how to get steps 1 and 2 started, but that's about all I know.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Job #]
ORDER BY [Job #] DESC) AS 'RN'
,count(*) over(partition by [Job #]) as maxrn
```

[Some Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJFoc.png)

I appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: All of your columns are data type `pixel`?! Providing data as text, with DDL, would make it easier for us to help you. Providing a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that creates and populates the table would be even better. And minimize. If there are a dozen columns that have nothing to do with the problem then why do we have to wade through them? That also makes it easier for you to show the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the missing piece to your puzzle is a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You can't reference a windowed function unless it is first in a common table expression or sub-query. Here's how I would approach your problem. You'll also want your `order by` clause in the `row_number()` function to include the way you want the job records ordered. For example, you might want to have them evaluated with the newest `[Date Last Issue]` as the last record or the first record in the partition.

If you only want to show the top Job # record, you would need to add another `row_number()` function (e.g. "RowNumberDesc"), but with [Job #] being ordered descending. Then you could add a where clause to the outer query to limit where RowNumberDesc = 1.

```
with cte as (
    select
        [Job #]
        ,[Date]
        ,[Variance Amt]
        ,[Job QTY] 
        ,[OpenQty] 
        ,[Part #] 
        ,[Material] 
        ,[PCS #] 
        ,[Matrl$$] 
        ,[Date Last Issue] 
        ,case when substring([PurchaseOrders],len([PurchaseOrders]),1) = '|' then substring([PurchaseOrders],1,len([PurchaseOrders])-1) else [PurchaseOrders] end [PurchaseOrders] 
        ,[PO$$] 
        ,[Date Last Rcvd] 
        ,[Wip Total] 
        ,[per pc] 
        ,[Standard Cost] 
        ,[DIFF] 
        ,[% of Profit] 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Job #] ORDER BY [Date Last Issue]) AS 'RN'
        ,count(*) over(partition by [Job #]) as maxrn
      FROM [VarianceView] 
)

SELECT  [Job #]
        ,[Date]
        ,[Variance Amt]
        ,[Job QTY] 
        ,[OpenQty] 
        ,[Part #] 
        ,[Material] 
        ,[PCS #] 
        ,[Matrl$$] 
        ,[Date Last Issue] 
        ,case when substring([PurchaseOrders],len([PurchaseOrders]),1) = '|' then substring([PurchaseOrders],1,len([PurchaseOrders])-1) else [PurchaseOrders] end [PurchaseOrders] 
        ,case when rn <> maxrn then 0 else [PO$$] end as [PO$$]
        ,[Date Last Rcvd] 
        ,case when rn <> maxrn then 0 else [Wip Total]      end as [Wip Total] 
        ,case when rn <> maxrn then 0 else [per pc]         end as [per pc] 
        ,case when rn <> maxrn then 0 else [Standard Cost]  end as [Standard Cost]
        ,case when rn <> maxrn then 0 else [DIFF]           end as [DIFF] 
        ,case when rn <> maxrn then 0 else [% of Profit]    end as [% of Profit] 
        ,rn as [ROW NO by JOB]
        ,maxrn as [MAX of ROW NO by JOB]
        FROM cte
        Order By [Job #]
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful and was exactly what I was missing. I was trying to reference the new tables in the same select statement but realized I couldn't do that, so I now know that CTEs are extremely useful. The last thing I was trying to do but not sure where to start is to change the Wip Total Column to sum up all the Matr$$ for that particular job and then add the PO$$ total which will now be zeroes for all but the last row. Will I have to do a separate subquery for this?

Comment: If you want to sum up the `[Matrl$$]` to a single line, then add another column inside the CTE like `,sum([Matrl$$]) over(partition by [Job #]) as [Job Matrl$$]` then you can zero it out on the other rows like the other columns outside the CTE.